# Passing POJO object to JSP

Tags: pojo

I want to pass an POJO object which will have three values(meterID,startDate,endDate) to JSP so that i display the details in the JSP.How to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is using the servlet->jsp combo in a MVC fashion.

Store the POJO or collection of them in the HttpServletRequest using the [setAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) (you will later get it in the jsp using request.[getAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)() )

and then forward the request to the jsp that will display the data.

request.[getRequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29)("/displayData.jsp").[forward](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)(request, response);

Note that the browser will not actively navigate to displayData.jsp since you handle it in the same request.

Basics on request dispatcher:
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-request-dispatcher-and-how-do-i-use-it.html?page=2

check this out too: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info